# Do I need multiple test fixtures for PDF (.AI) conversion with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I implemented a specialized utility for my team to batch convert AI files to other formats. It's using imagick and works well with the 1 AI file I used.  They to need officially support Illustrator v 9 and upward.

Is it sufficient enough to write a test for the utility using an AI file saved for Illustrator 9 and be confident that the embedded PDF data is similar enough that I don't have to add test AI files saved in other versions of AI?

In other words, if it can properly convert the PDF (in the AI file) saved with Illustrator v 9 then all other formats will convert 100% the same?
Or should I add test fixtures (AI files) for *each* other version of Illustrator because the natively supported PDF format changed significantly?
Or ... does ImageMagick already account for these differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the version of GhostScript installed because ImageMagick uses GhostScript for converting from PDF.

If the version of AI used is 9 and above, and if the .ai file is saved with PDF compatibility and your GhostScript is up to date .. then GhostScript should have no issue converting it regardless of the version of Illustrator (from 9 or above) that it was produced with. Illustrator specific information is saved at the end of the PDF file which affects the specific version of Illustrator and this is data that is not consequential to GhostScript.

Answer (score 0):

I tried same thing before. Simple answer is there is always something different. After trying for almost 3 months. I decide to use Illustrator Javascript API to convert files. And it works well.

Comment: Illustrator Javascript API is not an option. This is about ImageMagick specifically.  Currently I have no evidence to suggest that ImageMagick is not smart enough to understand different PDF versions and process each version correctly.  This is the crux of what I am trying to determine.